# Internet explorer can not download rtf files in PHP application

Tags: php, download, attachment, rtf

I have a problem with ie8 As ALWAYS. its not downloading rtf files i uploaded to server by my script. its saving in the database correctly

My download script is in php

```
$outname = stripslashes($attachment[0]['dis_attach_content']);
$type = stripslashes($attachment[0]['dis_attach_type']);

$name = stripslashes($attachment[0]['dis_attach_name']);
header("Content-type:" . $type);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
echo($outname);
exit;
```

This is giving the error:

[image]

Comment: None of the code that you've shown us shows the upload mechanism.  Have you tried outputting the exact URL that the code is looking for, and ensured the the file exists at that URL - and not just the reference in your database?

Comment: @BrendanBullen please see the my screen shot atached

Comment: @Coulton file is saving database correctly this error giving only to rtf file and IE only other all file types and all browers working fine

Comment: @Roshan Apologies, nothing showing for me so it wasn't clear you posted an error! Can you provide the text of the error? (I can't see it so I don't even know if that's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force the download:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Note; you should consider sending more headers:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: $type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));          
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
```

Comment: This isn't any use if the file doesn't exist or the URL is wrong.

Comment: Yes; but as he stated. He has problems with ie8. I assumed then it works in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Content-Disposition header to "attachment", like so (in PHP): where attachment was scripted.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

and add the following in .htaccess and add what ever extension that you want to download not only rtf

```
<FilesMatch "\.(rtf|txt|pdf|xls|xlsx|xlam|xlsb|xlsm|msg|doc|docx|mpg|jpg|png)">
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is unlikely to be a problem with IE.

Output `$name` to the browser, and check that this URL leads exactly to the file you're looking for on your server.

Is the URL exact to your domain?  You could try it with the exact URL eg: `http://website.com/file.rtf`

Comment: file is there and firefox/chrome downloading that file very well

Comment: @Roshan is the URL `$name` relative to your URL or is it exact?  `http://website.com/file.rtf`

Comment: The problem is.. IE period. Worst web broswer ever if you ask me.